# TLS Cipher Suite definitions

Tags: tls

Based off the various cipher suites available for TLS (which I am looking at here:https://www.thesprawl.org/research/tls-and-ssl-cipher-suites/), can anyone clarify if when the suite contains 'SHA', does it actually mean the orignal sha algorithm, or does it mean sha-1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's SHA-1; TLS uses either SHA-1, or on occasion a SHA-2 hash (and those would be listed as SHA256 or SHA384).  I've have never heard of anyone actually using SHA-0 (the hash algorithm originally proposed by NIST).

Comment: Great, that what I kinda figured, but just wanted to be sure.